# Changing root view controller of a iOS Window

Tags: ios, rootviewcontroller

Is the root view controller of a iOS Window usually initialized once in the beginning to a tab bar controller or navigation controller?  Is it okay to change the root view controller multiple times within an app?

I have a scenario where the top view is different based on user action. I was thinking of having a navigation controller with the top view controller having the image of the splash screen, and pushing/popping view controllers as required. Alternately, I can keep changing the window's top view controller. Which will be a better approach?

Comment: Could you be more precise? Which ViewController is changed based on user interaction?

Comment: Hey there!  Looks like most of your questions were answered, I included one about setting "rootViewController" multiple times below.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

It is more usual to use a "presented view controller" (`presentViewController:animated:completion:`). You can have as many of these as you like, effectively appearing in front of (and basically replacing) the root view controller. There doesn't have to be any animation if you don't want, or there can be. You can dismiss the presented view controller to go back to the original root view controller, but you don't have to; the presented view controller can just be there forever if you like.

Here's the section on presented view controllers from my book:

http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch19.html#_presented_view_controller

In this diagram (from earlier in that chapter), a presented view controller has completely taken over the app interface; the root view controller and its subviews are no longer in the interface. The root view controller still exists, but this is lightweight and doesn't matter.

[image]

Comment: Excellent explanation. My old trick of modally presenting a login screen from my app's root view controller doesn't work exactly right in iOS 8 (get problem described at http://goo.gl/cr9Pxk). I think I'll follow your lead and make two independent view controllers : one for login, and one for the main functionality.  (BTW, it must frustrating rewriting, re-type setting, gather new screen shots, etc... for a technology that changes so fast).

Answer (score 52):

iOS 8.0, Xcode 6.0.1, ARC enabled

Most of your questions were answered.  However, I can tackle one that I recently had to deal with myself.

**Is it okay, to change the root view controller multiple times, within an app?**

The answer is **yes**.  I had to do this recently to reset my UIView hierarchy after the initial UIViews that were part of the app. starting up were no longer needed.  In other words, you can reset your "rootViewController" from any other UIViewController at anytime after the app. "didFinishLoadingWithOptions".

**To do this...**

1) Declare a reference to your app. delegate (app called "Test")...

```
TestAppDelegate *testAppDelegate = (TestAppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
```

2) Pick a UIViewController you wish to make your "rootViewController"; either from storyboard or define programmatically...

  a) storyboard (make sure identifier, i.e. storyboardID, exists
      in Identity Inspector for the UIViewController):

```
UIStoryboard *mainStoryBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];

NewRootViewController *newRootViewController = [mainStoryBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"NewRootViewController"];
```

  b) programmatically (could addSubview, etc.)

```
UIViewController *newRootViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
newRootViewController.view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 50, 320, 430)];
newRootViewController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```

3) Putting it all together...

```
 testAppDelegate.window.rootViewController = newRootViewController;
[testAppDelegate.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

4) You can even throw in an animation...

```
testAppDelegate.window.rootViewController = newRootViewController;
    [testAppDelegate.window makeKeyAndVisible];

newRootViewController.view.alpha = 0.0;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:2.0 animations:^{

        newRootViewController.view.alpha = 1.0;

    }];
```

Hope this helps someone!  Cheers.

> The root view controller for the window.
>
> The root view controller provides the content view of the window.
>   Assigning a view controller to this property (either programmatically
>   or using Interface Builder) installs the view controller’s view as the
>   content view of the window. If the window has an existing view
>   hierarchy, the old views are removed before the new ones are
>   installed. The default value of this property is nil.

*Update 9/2/2015

As comments below point out, you must handle the removal of the old view controller when the new view controller is presented.  You may elect to have a transitional view controller in which you will handle this.  Here are a few hints on how to implement this:

```
[UIView transitionWithView:self.containerView
                  duration:0.50
                   options:options
                animations:^{

                    //Transition of the two views
                    [self.viewController.view removeFromSuperview];
                    [self.containerView addSubview:aViewController.view];

                }
                completion:^(BOOL finished){

                    //At completion set the new view controller.
                    self.viewController = aViewController;

                }];
```

Comment: Be really careful when replacing the rootViewController like this, because if the rootViewController was presenting another viewcontroller modally, this one will remain in the window hierarchy even after you replace the rootViewController (unless you dismiss it first).

Comment: Hey ale84, do we have a workaround for this problem?

Comment: @Sahil Kapoor - I have never found this to be the case, stackoverflow.com/a/5130560/4018041, the -(void)resignKeyWindow is invoked automatically when a window resigns the keyWindowStatus; this is reset after you send -makeKeyAndVisible to *.window. However, this might be true for UIViews and might have also existed before iOS7.0+. In fact, I can't access the *.windows array that some articles refer to.

Comment: It happens when modally presented view controller tries to change root view controller of window. You might be able to notice if you have transparent navigation bar.  
Workaround was to call dismiss it with animation set to false and change root view controller in it's completion block.

' self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: { () -> Void in
// Change Root vc here
                })
'

Comment: @Sahil Kapoor - Yes, nice concept for a work around.  Replacing the view controller like this will cause two view controllers to sit on top of each other, but this is only limited to two view controllers sitting on top of each other, once another view controller is presented, the last one of the three is dismissed automatically (at least this is what I am seeing from my tests).  I think that you can definitely dismiss the view controller after you don't need it anymore, i.e. after the animation finishes to present the new one, that'd be a better practice.

Comment: @serge-k, many thanks for solving my issue...http://stackoverflow.com/q/37325818/3633534.... using your 3rd point i fixed my issue

Comment: You can also use [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow to access... well... the key window.

Comment: @SahilKapoor thanks for advice to use completion block, previous root isn't removed correctly if replace it synchronously with dismiss on iOS11.

Answer (score 40):

From comments on serge-k's answer I have built a working solution with a workaround of strange behavior when there is a modal view controller presented over the old rootViewController:

```
extension UIView {
    func snapshot() -> UIImage {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(bounds.size, false, UIScreen.mainScreen().scale)
        drawViewHierarchyInRect(bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
        let result = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return result
    }
}

extension UIWindow {
    func replaceRootViewControllerWith(_ replacementController: UIViewController, animated: Bool, completion: (() -> Void)?) {
        let snapshotImageView = UIImageView(image: self.snapshot())
        self.addSubview(snapshotImageView)

        let dismissCompletion = { () -> Void in // dismiss all modal view controllers
            self.rootViewController = replacementController
            self.bringSubview(toFront: snapshotImageView)
            if animated {
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4, animations: { () -> Void in
                    snapshotImageView.alpha = 0
                }, completion: { (success) -> Void in
                    snapshotImageView.removeFromSuperview()
                    completion?()
                })
            }
            else {
                snapshotImageView.removeFromSuperview()
                completion?()
            }
        }
        if self.rootViewController!.presentedViewController != nil {
            self.rootViewController!.dismiss(animated: false, completion: dismissCompletion)
        }
        else {
            dismissCompletion()
        }
    }
}
```

To replace the rootViewController just use:

```
let newRootViewController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("BlackViewController")
UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow!.replaceRootViewControllerWith(newRootViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Hope this helps :)
tested on iOS 8.4; also tested for navigation controllers support (should support also tab bar controllers etc., but I did not test it)

**Explanation**

If there is a modal view controller presented over old rootViewController, the rootViewController is replaced, but the old view still remains hanging below the new rootViewController's view (and can be seen for example during Flip Horizontal or Cross Dissolve transition animations) and the old view controller hierarchy remains allocated (which may cause severe memory problems if replacement happens multiple times).

So the only solution is to dismiss all modal view controllers and then replace the rootViewController. A snapshot of the screen is placed over the window during dismissal and replacement to hide the ugly flashing process.

Comment: Nice solution, but how can you fix it for a `TabBarController`?

Comment: Does this work if you have several nested vcs? Like rootvc>modalvc>modalvc>modalvc>modalvc etc

Comment: Answering myself, I think it actually does. From the docs of dismiss: "If you present several view controllers in succession, thus building a stack of presented view controllers, calling this method on a view controller lower in the stack dismisses its immediate child view controller and all view controllers above that child on the stack."

Comment: Crash on iOS 13 simulator with error `Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`

Answer (score 6):

You can change the window's rootViewController throughout the application life cycle.

```
UIViewController *viewController = [UIViewController alloc] init];
[self.window setRootViewController:viewController];
```

When you change the rootViewController, you still may want to add a UIImageView as a subview on the window to act as a splash image. I hope this makes sense, something like this:

```
- (void) addSplash {
    CGRect rect = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds;
    UIImageView *splashImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:rect];
    splashImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"splash.png"];
    [self.window addSubview:splashImage];
}

- (void) removeSplash {
    for (UIView *view in self.window.subviews) {
      if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]]) {
        [view removeFromSuperview];
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have a problem when I use setRootViewController. The problem is the view controller stacks still be kept after the rootviewcontroller replaced. Don't know where those coming from. I call storyboard.instantiate to create a new view controller.

Answer (score 3):

For iOS8, we also need to set below two parameters to YES.

```
providesPresentationContextTransitionStyle
definesPresentationContext
```

Here is my code for presenting transparent model view controller under navigation controller for iOS 6 and above.

```
ViewController *vcObj = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:NSStringFromClass([ViewController class]) bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *navCon = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:vcObj];

if ([[UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion floatValue] >= 8.0) {

    navCon.providesPresentationContextTransitionStyle = YES;
    navCon.definesPresentationContext = YES;
    navCon.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationOverCurrentContext;

    [self presentViewController:navCon animated:NO completion:nil];
}
else {

    AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    [self presentViewController:navCon animated:NO completion:^{
        [navCon dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:^{
            appDelegate.window.rootViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;
            [self presentViewController:navCon animated:NO completion:nil];
            appDelegate.window.rootViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen;

        }];
    }];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

For the people who try to change the root view controller for **iOS 13 and later** then you need to change root view controller using `SceneDelegate`'s `window` property.

```
class SceneDelegate: UIResponder, UIWindowSceneDelegate {

  var window: UIWindow?
  static let shared = SceneDelegate()

  func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {

    guard let _ = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }

    //other stuff
  }
}
```

Created a utility class which has the method to change the root view controller.

```
class AppUtilities {

  class func changeRootVC( _ vc: UIViewController) {

    SceneDelegate.shared.window?.rootViewController = vc
    SceneDelegate.shared.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
  }
}
```

You can change root view controller in following way.

```
//Here I'm setting HomeVC as root view controller

if let homeVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)?.instantiateViewController(identifier: "HomeVC") as? HomeVC {

    let rootVC = UINavigationController(rootViewController: homeVC)
    AppUtilities.changeRootVC(rootVC)

  }
}
```