# How to remove old ViewControllers from stack

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift

I wonder how I can remove my old VC's from the stack?

When I start my app there is a Hamburger icon/menu button in the header.

What I want to do is when a user logs into my app I want to set the VC/ Account page to be the root view so that I don't see underlying VC's when looking in the inspector.

So more or less instead of having a back button I want to add a menu button in  the header on the account page.

I already tried this but I can't get it to work:

```
let storyboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle())
let yourViewController: ViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("respectiveIdentifier") as! ViewController

let navigationController = self.window?.rootViewController as! UINavigationController
navigationController.setViewControllers([yourViewController], animated: true)
```

Comment: where did u put that code ?

Comment: @Mr.T In the VC that comes before the last VC that I want to make the root VC

Comment: can u pls clarify that you want to remove the VC from navigation stack or from the app memory stack ?

Comment: @Mr.T what is the difference? I want to reset my navigation stack I guess. Making the account page the new root one

Comment: This question could be helpful. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15774003/changing-root-view-controller-of-a-ios-window

Comment: Why you do not use `UIViewController` instead of `UINavigationViewController`? Use `presentViewController` to show a view and dismiss it when another view controller shown.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use:

```
navigationController!.viewControllers.removeAtIndex((navigationController?.viewControllers.count)! - 2)
```

Use this **after** your new controller is loaded, so this basically removes the controller previous to the last on the stack. Let me know if you have any issues implementing it.