# Swift: ViewController A to ViewController B to ViewController C

Tags: swift, segue

Having Segue navigated to *nth* `ViewController` (all separate ones: not navigation/tabbed) How do I get to the first one from the last using `Xcode 8, iOS 10, Swift`?

Comment: So you, want to go from _ViewController A_ to _ViewController C_ without passing by _ViewController B_ ? is it like that? Can you clarify that in your question, maybe a little diagram could help.

Comment: I use CTRL+Drag Segue starting from VCA -> VCB ->...VC9. Now when I am done at VC9, I want to return to VCA (almost as if the app is restarting). Think like registration Kiosk. When one user is done with his/her registration the app returns to first one.

Comment: just a sidetone: All my view controllers have some background video playing on viewDidLoad()

Comment: Maybe window.rootViewcontroller can help you. Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15774003/changing-root-view-controller-of-a-ios-window