# Loggin out after auto-login in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3

In my AppDelegate, I check for a client token in my keychain. If found, I make my Dashboard ViewController the root view controller, hence autologging in. But, when logging out, I can't call dismiss because the dashboard VC is the root view controller. So when user presses log out, I check if I can dismiss, if not then I just segue.
However, I'd like to remove the DashboardVC from memory in case I segued. How do I do that?

EDIT: Not using a navigation controller 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Basically you have two options here:

- Open a new view controller (segue) and remove the previous one from navigation controller stack. See [Removing viewcontrollers from navigation stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10281545/removing-viewcontrollers-from-navigation-stack)
- Change your window's `rootViewController`. See [Changing root view controller of a iOS Window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15774003/changing-root-view-controller-of-a-ios-window)

Comment: I don't have a navigation controller though. Sorry I should've mentioned that in my question

Comment: @AymanA.Hashisho You can add a navigation controller. If this is not an option then go with changing `rootViewController`.