# Dismiss all view controllers below current view controller swift

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I am using a UINavigationController.

Lets say I have these stacks

```
VC1 -> VC2 -> VC3 
VC1 -> VC3
VC1 -> VC2 -> VC4 -> VC3
```

In all cases, how can I dismiss all VC's below VC3 when it is the current view controller.

VC3 is connected to a TabBarController if this make a difference.

Comment: you want VC3 `TabBarController` as root View and remove the whole `UINavigationController` with VC1 and VC2 ?

Comment: pretty much yh @Amit

Comment: you can directly change the root View controller by adding `self.view.window?.rootViewController = TabBarController` in VC2.

Comment: Since you have navigation controller, what do you mean by "dismiss" the view controllers? Why do you need to do this?

Comment: I dont want the user to swipe back from VC3, but I can't disable the gesture recognizer on individual VC's. I will try your suggestion thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `VC2`, use `setViewControllers` method to push `VC3` and to remove the rest,

```
self.navigationController?.setViewControllers([VC3], animated: true)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove a view controller from the navigation controller stack like that:
`self.navigationController?.viewControllers.remove(at: index)`

Comment: sorry i didnt specify in question but the number of VC's below VC3 is ambiguos. There can be 1 view controller or 3 view controllers

Comment: In that case all you need to do is just set the VC3 as the only VC, like the answer below. Basically you should set the array by setting `setViewControllers` with the top most VC in your case the VC3.

Answer (score 0):

In your scenario it's better to change the application's root view from `UINavigationController` to `UITabBarcontroller`.

You can achieve that by doing in any `VC`:

```
self.view.window?.rootViewController = TabBarController
```

To know more about it you can check this link:

- [Changing root view controller of a iOS Window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15774003/changing-root-view-controller-of-a-ios-window)